# How to assign separate memory spaces of same type of class

Tags: iphone

Hi my program adds small Images to main view. I have this undo button to remove recently added Image(subView). It works ok when it has all different Images, But when there are two same images it occurs error.
I think this is because it both points the same original png file. But I have no idea how to fix it. Please give me some hint.

```
add{  
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pah%d",tagNum]];
    TouchImageView *touchImageView = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    imageCounter++;
    touchImageView.tag = imageCounter;
    touchImageView.image = image;
    touchImageView.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 230.0);
    [view addSubview:touchImageView];
}

undo{
       [[self.view viewWithTag:imageCounter] removeFromSuperview];
    imageCounter--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that its your problem here but  `imageNamed:` caches the image in memory with an internal caching system. Every time you ask for `[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"]` you get the same UIImage instance.

You probably want to be using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead which returns a unique instance of a UIImage.

Try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It showed weird error. Just right before my code above, I'm adding mainview to the screen such like "[self.view insertSubview:photoViewCon.view atIndex:0];". And it freezes on that point after second attempt of adding image.

Answer (score 0):

if you just have to remove recently added image...
then each time where you are adding the image store its reference like this - it will work well with ARC...

```
 UIImageView *imageView = touchImageView;
```

then in your remove Recently added image button click's

```
 for(UIImageView *iV in view.subviews)
 {
    if(iV == imageView)
    {
       [iV removeFromSuperView];
    }
 }
```

i think it will work ...